# Team Foundation Server - source code setup

Tags: tfs

I am currently in the process of setting up TFS for a new project at work and came up with the idea of only having the following 3 directories in the root of source.

- trunk
- branches
- tags

trunk - this will contain the code-base from which all other branches derive from.

branches - this will contain all branches of the code-base used during development.

tags - will contain all releases tagged using the following structure

tags\project x\version-1.1\staging

tags\project x\version-1.1\live

However, this tagging directory structure got me thinking, their is no way to distinguish between releases done from the trunk and those from a specific branch.

Therefore is it best to have the tags folder within both the trunk and each separate branch?

Answer (score 0):

When you build a production release version, you should tag it. The tag could include its origin, e.g.

-> Tags

```
-> Production from Trunk (02/02/2013 17:45:21)

-> Production from Branch [EBF - Incident 90210] (03/02/2013 19:13:11)
```

This should be possible to automate with most continuous integration tools.